# Issue with getting prototype bean from application context

Tags: spring

I have a requirement where in i have to fetch few stateful bean inside a loop of a class which is my processor.This processor bean itself is a singleton bean. Now the problem is at one place i am able to successfully get beans from application context but in other case i am getting a proxy object. I am using annotations to define scope of bean and using component scan.

Case 1 - Interface1

Class A implements Interface1

applicationContext.getBean("a",A.class);  this returns object of class A successfully .class A is prototype bean

Case 2 -interface2
Class B implements Interface2 (class B is prototype bean)
applicationContext.getBean("b",B.class); 
 this throws runtime exception complaining about mismatch in type
If i do  B b= (B)applicationContext.getBean("b",); 
This gives type cast exception
If i do
applicationContext.getBean("b"); 
 Then it returns proxy object.
Iam not able to understand this behaviour.

Any suggestions or help would be great....

Comment: Please add the code

Comment: Also, are you using any frameworks that might be responsible for proxying your beans? AspectJ, for example?

Comment: Yes Thomas. There was aspect around the bean hence application context was giving proxy object instead of bean.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if in the application there are aspects around the prototype bean then by default application context will return the proxy object and type casting wont be possible,